# Document not detecting input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I've had this problem for awhile now and I can't seem to fix it no matter what I do. 
Basically, my input is not retrieving the value that the user types in the input for some reason..

Here is my code:

```
$('#aid').one('click', function () { 
    $('.prompt').prepend('<tr class="task"><td class="cell-icon"></td>' +
        '<td class="cell-title"><div>User\'s Object: <input id="inputObject" type="text" style="margin-top: 2px;margin-left:2px"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp; Amount: <input id="inputAmount"' +
        'type="text" style="margin-top:2px;margin-left:2px; padding-right: 0px"></input></div></td>' +
        '<td class="cell-status hidden-phone hidden-tablet"><a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:3px">Submit</a></td>' +
        '<td class="cell-time align-right">Just Now</td></div>' +
        '</tr>');
});
$('.btn').click(function () {
    console.log("click");
    var input = document.getElementById('inputObject').value;
    console.log(input);
});
```

Everything works fine including both clicks, but for some reason it just won't display the input value to the console.

I've also tried: `$('#inputObject').val();` but that didn't work either.

I really hope that someone can help me here!

Comment: Is the missing close quote on the first jQuery selector a typo or part of the problem?

Comment: What happens if you replace the `console.log` with an `alert`?

Comment: Replace `$('#aid)` by `$('#aid')`

Comment: no that was just a copy pasting error my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method: use **delegate**.

```
$('body').delegate('.btn', "click", function() {
   var inp = document.getElementById("inputObject").value;
   console.log(inp); 
});
```

---

**Explanation** from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp:

The `delegate()` method **attaches** one or more **event handlers** for specified elements that are children of selected elements, and specifies a function to run when the events occur.

Event handlers attached using the `delegate()` method **will work for** both current and **FUTURE elements** (like a new element created by a script).

Comment: As of jQuery version 1.7, the on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers for selected elements.

Comment: Yes, it's also specified in the link above. This is why I gave you a like, because you had a good solution. But, delegate has an advantage: the order of parameters. To my mind it's nicer to know which is the `element`, then which is the `event`.

Comment: Everybody has their own ways, to my mind it's nicer to use on() :)

Comment: I agree. Only for the order of parameters I like `delegate`, but `on` sounds better - it's more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your HTML code dynamically so try using:

```
$(document).on("click",".btn", function(){
    do stuff here... 
});
```